# Webflux and Resilience4j retry issue

Tags: java, spring-webflux, resilience4j, resilience4j-retry

wanted to ask a basic question about webflux and resilience4j's retry.
We are running Java SpringBoot with Webflux and Resilience4J (not Spring Cloud Circuit Breaker).
While running the application its giving error (Somehow full stack trace is not coming for me) :

```
due to exception [reactor.core.publisher.Mono.retryWhen(Ljava/util/function/Function;)Lreactor/core/publisher/Mono;]
```

Code to build the Retry bean is as follows (we are not using YAML based configuration):

```
    @Bean
public Retry retryConfig(ResilienceCCMConfig resilienceCCMConfig) {
    RetryConfig config = RetryConfig.custom().maxAttempts(5)
            .waitDuration(Duration.of(1, SECONDS))
            .retryExceptions(ServerException.class)
            .ignoreExceptions(ClientException.class)
            .build();
    return RetryRegistry.of(config).retry("retry-config", config);
}
```

Now we are calling our web client's POST method as below with bean injected from above :

```
    @Autowired
private Retry retryConfig;


return webClient.post().uri(url)
            .headers(httpHeaders -> getItemHeaders(httpHeaders, tenantId, bannerId, correlationId))
            .body(itemServiceRequestMono, ItemServiceRequest.class)
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, clientResponse -> {
                LOGGER.error("Error");
                if (clientResponse.statusCode().is5xxClientError()) {
                    throw new Exception("Something went wrong ");
                           
                }
               
                return Mono.empty();
            })
            .bodyToMono(MyResponse.class)
            .transform(RetryOperator.of(retryConfig))
            .onErrorResume(ex -> myFallbackMethod(ex));
```

POM dependency :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>resilience4j-reactor</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId> io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Please help .